# Orbeon - run batch file

Tags: batch-processing, orbeon

I need to run a kettle(ktr) file from the orbeon or more specifically from the xpl file. I was thinking of running a batch file but i cant find any step to do it. How can i run the batch/ktr file from within the xpl file?

Answer (score 0):

To run external commands from XPL you van use the undocumented `oxf:execute-processor`, for instance (borrowed to [XForms Unit](http://xformsunit.org/trac/browser/resources/apps/xformsunit/suite.xpl?rev=f7d9d62cd0e8328989b2dab0fcb03ecdb4d74e00)):

```
<p:processor name="oxf:execute-processor">
    <p:input name="config" href="#control" transform="oxf:xslt">
        <exec executable="/home/vdv/projects/xformsunit/resources/apps/xformsunit/browser-run.sh"
            xsl:version="2.0">
            <arg
                line=" http://localhost:8080/orbeon/xformsunit/suite/{/*/name}/results?implementation=xsltforms&amp;uid={/*/uid}"
            />
        </exec>
    </p:input>
    <p:output name="stdout" id="stdout" debug="stdout"/>
    <p:output name="stderr" id="stderr" debug="stderr"/>
    <p:output name="result" id="result" debug="result"/>
</p:processor>
```

AFAIK this processor hasn't been documented but you should be able to find more examples [on the mailing list](http://discuss.orbeon.com/Execute-processor-help-needed-td43816.html).